# Proof of the chain rule for fractional derivatives in F.M.Christ and M.I.Weinsten's paper

Tags: harmonic-analysis

In the paper: Dispersion of small amplitude Solutions of the generalized Korteweg-de Vries equation, JOURNAL OF FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS 100,87-109 (1991).
 I find a mistake in the proof of proposition 3.1 (page 91), and the mistake is as following:
  in page 93, Below formula (3.3) and the word "Note that", the righthandside of the inequality should be 2(MF')(u)(x) instead of 2M(F'(u))(x). Therefore, this proof is false. Is the conclusion of proposition 3.1 still true?[enter link description here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212369190103C)

Comment: Could you make your question self-contained, or at least provide a link to a freely accessible PDF file of the paper you ask about?

Comment: I realize that the paper is over 20 years old, but since it and in particular, the fractional chain rule result, are highly cited, did you reach out to the authors? This doesn't seem to be just an issue of notation, and the rest of the argument uses $M(F'(u))$--in particular, the maximal theorem estimate $\|M(F'(u)\|_{L^{p}}\lesssim\|F'(u)\|_{L^{p}}$.